# what's the word for showing a person is clever but just in trivial matters?

Tags: adjectives

My friend wonders that is there any word can describe this, just a word. I found "clever-clever ",but it is not so capable.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are asking about someone that only knows about subjects to a trivial level, then a **dilettante** is a person that shows interest or skill in an activity or subject at a purely superficial level.

From the Cambridge dictionary:

> a person who is or seems to be interested in a subject, but whose understanding of it is not very deep or serious

**Dilettante** can have negative connotations, however. You might consider **smatterrer** for a similar meaning without the connotations, but it's a little dated as a term.

Comment: @AndyT good point. You may well be right. I'll edit my post to reflect the nature of my answer.

Comment: With your edit, I think this answer works. +1

Answer (score -3):

Try Erudite;
It means 'having or showing great knowledge or learning.'
"Ken could turn any conversation into an erudite discussion"
But using the word erudite in a sentence may not signify one's erudition.

Comment: Not really.  Erudite usually indicates a deeper level of learning than the question seeks.

Comment: I think erudite is the opposite of what the OP is asking; the question is about people that are only good at trivial matters, which suggests lacking a deep understanding of any subject